# Find the second element from DOM using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have a 2 elements on my web page that has the same class name and I am trying to access the second element and I am unable to do that.

The span looks like this:

```
<span class="REPORTING_DASHBOARDS__link navMenuLabel ">

Dashboards

</span>
```

My code for this part looks like this:

```
dashboards_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".REPORTING_DASHBOARDS__link.navMenuLabel")[1]                                                          
dashboards_button.click()
```

Comment: You can try something like `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("REPORTING_DASHBOARDS__link navMenuLabel")[1]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use `find_elements_` instead of `find_element_` to get all element.
`find_element` returns only first possible element.

```
dashboards_button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".REPORTING_DASHBOARDS__link.navMenuLabel")[1]
```

Or using nth-child if it is under same parent with find_element

```
dashboards_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".REPORTING_DASHBOARDS__link.navMenuLabel:nth-child(1)")
```

if it is not under same parent, change it to xpath,

```
dashboards_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[contains(@class,'REPORTING_DASHBOARDS__link navMenuLabel')][1]")
```